# My dart function only add one record to List

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This function add only one record from firebase but according my conditions it should add all the records where the conditions true

function:

```
final Set<Marker> _markers = <Marker>{}; //My marker List

Future<void> markSetss() async {
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('stations')
    .where('norequest', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 5)
    .get();

List<Map<String?, dynamic>> results = querySnapshot.docs
    .map((doc) => {
          _markers.add(
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(doc['norequest'].toString()),
              position: LatLng(doc['coor'].latitude, doc['coor'].longitude),
            ),
          ),
        } as Map<String, dynamic>)
    .toList();
}
```

Firebase records:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it because you set same `MarkerId` to the marker.
it should unique.

in you case :

```
markerId: MarkerId(doc['norequest'].toString()),
```

and based on data that you provide , the `doc['norequest']` same for all value which is `10`

try to make `markerId` unique for each marker.
you can use any value that make is unique.
or you can combine 2 value

```
markerId: MarkerId('${(doc['norequest']}-${(doc['place']}'),
```

with this each marker will have different id, and will not replacing eachother

Comment: markerId: MarkerId('${(doc['norequest']}-${(doc['place']}') this is not working and i tried to use Uuid package to provide id that's alson not working it only takes 1 set of values to my list also i changed doc['norequest'] value to be different